# jquery slide menu on the left open on load

Tags: jquery, menu, slide

Any suggestion of plugins or fiddle examples how to realize menu at the left of the page with `slide` effect, animation and open/close button like on wookmark dot com done?

I already tried and look at:
http://apptitudes.fr/distrib/git/sliding_menu_js/demo/
http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/pageslide/
http://jpanelmenu.com/examples/jrespond/index.html
http://www.berriart.com/sidr/#usage (Sidr)

But they all closed by default. And seems slow down the page. Any suggestions? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any of the examples you linked, you can easily open the sliding nav programmatically on page load. E.g. in jquery:

```
$(function() {
   $('.show-menu-button').click();
});
```

Or use their built in `open` functions. E.g. the [JPanelMenu](http://jpanelmenu.com/index.html#api-open) has:

```
var jPM = $.jPanelMenu({
    menu: '#custom-menu-selector',
    trigger: '.custom-menu-trigger-selector'
});
jPM.on();
jPM.open(false); // don't animate on page load
```

Also, you should know that it's common when adding big javascript components to a page that things will slow down slightly. That's life.